# Pairs Trading Strategy: Signal Buy and Sell

Tags: r, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to set up a pairs trading strategy based on the stocks' spread. I have come up with the logic on how to enter a position for either a long or short.
I am struggling to grasp the concept of how I would:
(1) ignore the signal if I've already entered the position before exiting
(2) how I would create a signal to exit a position based on if a position is open
(3) calculate that return/max drawdown, etc.

```
library(quantmod)
library(tseries)
library(xts)
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)


#disable sci notation
options(scipen=999)



stock1 <- "TECHM.NS"
stock2 <- "HCLTECH.NS"

stock1 <-  getSymbols(stock1, src = "yahoo", auto.assign = F)
stock2 <- getSymbols(stock2, src = "yahoo", auto.assign = F)


##Keep only adjusted close for analysis
stock1 <- stock1[, grep("Adjusted", colnames(stock1))] #must use grep for time series
stock2 <- stock2[, grep("Adjusted", colnames(stock2))] #must use grep for time series


#shortens data set for analysis
cut_off_date <- as.Date("2014-01-01")
stock1 <- stock1[index(stock1) >= cut_off_date]
stock2 <- stock2[index(stock2) >= cut_off_date]

#Replaces NA values with previous observations
stock1 <- na.locf(stock1)
stock2 <- na.locf(stock2)

# Delt() converts closing prices to returns. By default it calculates one period  return
ret_stock1 <- Delt(stock1)
ret_stock2 <- Delt(stock2)



ret_stock1 <- round(ret_stock1+1, 4) #rounds the daily returns
ret_stock1[1] <- 1 #sets the first day equal to $1 invested. 
norm_stock1 <- cumprod(ret_stock1) #computes the cumulative return through all trade days




ret_stock2 <- round(ret_stock2+1, 4) #rounds the daily returns - why the +1?
ret_stock2[1] <- 1 #sets the first day equal to $1 invested
norm_stock2 <- cumprod(ret_stock2) #computes the cumulative return through all trade days

#calculate and plot the differences between the two
diff <- norm_stock1 - norm_stock2

#Create short and long signals
n <- 0.5

me_dynamic <- rollapply(diff, 10, mean)
std_dynamic <- rollapply(diff, 10, sd)

ub <- me_dynamic + n*std_dynamic #upperbound
lb <- me_dynamic - n*std_dynamic #lowerbound
```

Here's my approach to signal which stock to long and which stock to short.

```
enterhigh <- ifelse(diff > ub, 1, 0)
enterlow <-  ifelse(diff < lb, 1, 0)
norm1position <- ifelse((enterhigh == 1 | enterlow ==1) & norm_stock1 > 
norm_stock2, -1, 
                    ifelse((enterhigh ==1 | enterlow ==1), 1,0))

norm2position <- ifelse(norm1position == -1, 1, ifelse(norm1position ==1, -1, 0))
```

If you have a totally different way to do this, I'd love to learn that too. 
I've seen examples such as: https://analyticsprofile.com/algo-trading/pair-trading-part-1-code-distance-based-pair-trading-strategy-in-r/. However these lack the ability to really link an action to the strategy.

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Programming logic, yes.

Comment: You might look into [quantstrat](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat) and one of the demo's in the package is a pair trade. Or you can find the demo code [here](https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat/blob/master/demo/pair_trade.R) on their github package

Comment: I tried quantstrat. As a personal preference I didn't like it because of how it made use of it's own environment. I'm 1/3 of a programmer as I am a statstician. It's too good of a package for me.